# Rails Params Hash not working anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need some quick help please.

All of a sudden, my rails 4 app wont work anymore. It says `undefined method 'permit' for #<Array: ... >` every time I do a form-post. This happens in every controller in the `[class]_params` method. The logs state, that the params come in as follows:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "page"=>["This is a page title", "this is the pages content"]}
```

As you can see, the params for `page` do not come in properly as a hash but as a flat array list. Why is this? I use `form_for`. I monitored the network traffic on my local machine and the POST requests all look like this:

```
utf8=✓
authenticity_token=...
page[title]=This is a page title
page[content]=This is the pages content
```

So on the request site, everything seems alright. Why does rails suddenly merge it all down to a flat array??? I don't even know where to look anymore...

**EDIT:**

OK, I got one hint. The requests where the params used to be correct had the following log entries:

```
Processing by PagesController#update as HTML
```

whereas the messed up params only happened when `HTML` was swapped with `*/*`:

```
Processing by PagesController#update as */*
```

Still no idea, why that suddenly happened. And it says that with all requests now. Any idea what causes that? And what does `*/*` even mean?

**EDIT 2:**

OK one more thing for now and then i'll leave it. I noticed in the logs that the processing as html stopped right at 12:00.

Last timestamp with processing as `HTML`: `2014-03-01T11:59:33.758744`

First timestamp with processing as `*/*`: `2014-03-01T12:00:21.575461`

All further requests where processed as `*/*`. I am suspicious about that change right around 12:00, maybe some server updating bullshit I don't know about? Or am I getting paranoid? No idea where else to look, though.

Oh and one more question: Is there a way to show in rails server output/logfiles the raw http-request that rails received? Maybe that will give a hint.

Comment: Has anything changed in your config/routes.rb file lately? Are you sure no code changed since it was working before? Are others working on this project?

Comment: No I'm working alone on this. This is also a pretty small project. routs.rb did not change but I will double check that again. Last thing I did before everything went messy was changing the `update` method in the `PagesController`. But this issue effects all controllers, so that can't be it. Also, the update method is'nt even called because it stops right at `page_params`. No config files where changed directly before this issue.